# MySQL - Como pegar o nome da tabela de onde veio o resultado?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho o seguinte código em mysql:

```
(SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE idUsuario = "1") UNION 
(SELECT * FROM saida WHERE idUsuario = "1")
```

Está tudo funcionando mas eu preciso saber de qual das 2 tabelas que veio o resultado, como faço isso ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode tentar:

```
(SELECT 'entrada' as tipo, entrada.* FROM entrada WHERE idUsuario = "1") UNION 
(SELECT 'saida' as tipo, saida.* FROM saida WHERE idUsuario = "1")
```

Assim, em cada registro terá uma coluna `tipo` com o valor `entrada` ou `saida`.